# Winform Simple Link

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

I use a `LabelLink` contorl in a `WinForm`.

On form load I set the desired  link:

```
LinkLabel.Link link = new LinkLabel.Link();
link.LinkData = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
linkLabel1.Links.Add(link);
```

On click :

```
void LinkLabel1LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {   
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData as string);
    }
```

The link is gray and nothing happens when I click on it.
What is missing?

Comment: Do you register the event handler somewhere in code that you haven't shown?

Comment: Set break point on that `Start()` and see if you get there and check a value of `e.Link.LinkData` (if you get `"Ask a question"`, then you know what is wrong).

Comment: Please check my answer and comment...

Comment: @adv12 Yes I did `this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.LinkLabel1LinkClicked);`

Comment: On second look, I think @Sinatr is onto something.  Is `link` the only link you add to `this.linklabel1.Links`?  If so, it looks like you're overwriting the URL with "Ask a question".

Comment: @adv12, Even after deleting the problematic code line of "Ask a question" the linkLabel behaves just like a regular label. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sinatr Even deleting this line does not matter. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sinatr still has a good idea: put a breakpoint on the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` line, both to make sure you're actually getting there and to inspect variables.

Comment: @adv12, No, I do not manage to the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` line since the linklabel behaves like a embedded label which does not invoke the `OnClick` event at all. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LinkLabel.Link link = new LinkLabel.Link();
link.LinkData = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
linkLabel1.Links.Add(link);
this.linkLabel1.Links[0].LinkData = "Ask a question";
linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.LinkLabel1LinkClicked‌​);
```

and

```
void LinkLabel1LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{   
    string url;
    url = e.Link.LinkData.ToString();

    if (!url.Contains("://"))
        url = "http://" + url;

    var myLink = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
    Process.Start(myLink);
    linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: No, nothing happens, the linkLabel behaves just like a regular label.